# Do neural networks accepts other than fixed size of input data?

Tags: python, machine-learning, image-processing, deep-learning, computer-vision

I am implementing a MultiLayer Perceptron , I am extracting the features of images using SIFT algorithm of image processing and I pass those features to the neural network , the features of images that I am considering are descriptors ,every image has different length of descriptors , some image has 200 descriptors and some image has 240 descriptors , means it's varying . But neural networks accepts fixed size of input data .
How can I pass this type of input to it if it accept varied input then how ?

Comment: the dimension of the input data needs to be fixed, but you can play around with other parameters

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the questions (and answers) you are looking for are below:

- https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/2008/how-can-neural-networks-deal-with-varying-input-sizes
- [How are neural networks used when the number of inputs could be variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1766461/how-are-neural-networks-used-when-the-number-of-inputs-could-be-variable?rq=1)

But in your case, at the end you could get rid of the problem by simply using some image embedding. You could take some neural net that is pre-trained for example, [Inception v3](https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.00567) that extracts `N` features from image, and you will always have constant input, of `N` features.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try to pad your data to a fixed size(like the maximum length of your descriptors) vector with all 0 or mean value of this vector.